# How to extract text from .kdf files?

Tags: sqlite, kindle

I'm working with a .kdf file (making a book for Kindle) and want to extract the text from it because I made changes to it and need to update my .doc file. How can I extract the text? An inspection of the file suggests that it is an SQLite database file:

```bash
head -c 15 book.kdf # => SQLite format 3
```

When I run `sqlite3 book.kdf`, I find no tables, though when I peruse the file with `less` I recognize parts of the text of the book, albeit in no format I understand.

Is there a way to extract the text?

Comment: How are you seeing if there are any tables or not?

Comment: @Shawn : I run `.tables`

Comment: Hmm. Something might have dropped all tables in the file before you got it and didn't vacuum afterwards. Does `PRAGMA freelist_count` give a non-zero number?

Comment: @Shawn : it gives 0

Comment: And `PRAGMA page_count`?

Comment: @Shawn : whoops. It appears that my answers differ depending on whether I've already run commands like `.dump`. So I've started a new sqlite session, and `PRAGMA freelist_count` gives `12`. `PRAGMA page_count` gives "Error: malformed database schema (?)"

Comment: Make sure you're using the latest version of the sqlite3 shell (3.29) and if it still happens the file is probably hosed. The undocumented `.recover` command *might* be able to salvage something.

Answer (score 0):

I was not able to figure out how to read the SQLite3 file inside the KPF file, but you may have another avenue if you generated the KPF from an ePub.

```bash
unzip mybook.kpf -d mybook/
cd mybook/
unzip book.epub -d book/
cd book/
ls *.xhtml
```

Those xhtml files should be your chapters/etc.

*If* you generated the KPF from an ePub, *and* it was stored in the KPF, then you should be able to extract your text from it.

I'm debugging a separate issue with a KPF, so hopefully I'll have more info on the SQLite file soon, but dumping, recovering, etc all did not work. If you look at the binary file, the text is in there, but inaccessible for whatever reason.